# How to get Selected Date with Current TimeStamp in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, date, jsf-2, primefaces, timestamp

I am selecting a date from a `<p:calendar>` component and I want to have the current time appended to the selected date.

[image]

Assume that now the time is `12/13/13 04:30:12` .

I had selected the date as `12/17/13` from the calendar and I want to save it as `12/17/13 04:30:12`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your custom `@FacesConverter` and apply it on the `<p:calendar>` component.

```
@FacesConverter("timestampConverter")
public class TimestampConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, 
                              UIComponent uIComponent, 
                              String string) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
        Date date = null;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            date = sdf.parse(string);
            calendar.setTime(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, now.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, now.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        Timestamp result = new Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, 
                              UIComponent uIComponent, 
                              Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }    
        return object.toString();
    }
}
```

In the `getAsObject(..)` method you can get the `String` that's received from the front-end, *append* the current time and construct a `Timestamp` object as a result.

The snippet from the facelet (plus my testing button) looks like this:

```
<h:form>
    <p:calendar value="#{myBean.date}" >
        <f:converter converterId="timestampConverter" />
    </p:calendar>
    <p:commandButton title="Test" action="#{myBean.testAction}" />
<h:form>
```

and in the `myBean` class there should be a `date` property with the corresponding accessor methods.

```
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "myBean")
public class MyBean {
    private Date date;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        return date;
    }

    public String testAction() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YY HH:mm:ss");
        String output = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println("Selected date with timestamp: " + output);
    }
}
```

More info:

- [JSF Custom Converter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-custom010.htm)

Comment: The Convertor is Converting the Date as `Sun Dec 22 00:00:00 MST 2013` but i want it as `MM/dd/yyyy` I had used `<f:converDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>` but it is not happening.